# Remove border when hover a button Xamarin form UWP

Tags: xamarin, button, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

How to remove the rectangle border showing when hovering the button in Xamarin form UWP. I have referred the following link

[Remove border of button when hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040536/xamarin-uwp-how-to-get-rid-of-border-that-appears-when-hovering-over-button)

that we have to change border width property, that too failed because I am using a rounded corner button that border only came whenever hovering and clicking.

Following screenshots will display the scenario.

[Button - normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nnt2.png)

[Button - when hovers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnzx4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for my own question few minute after posting it.

you can override ButtonBackgroundPointerOver inside your App.xaml of UWP project.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
</Application.Resources>
```

I have found this from [Hover pointover background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562688/how-to-change-the-buttons-background-when-mouseover-in-uwp)